# What is the difference between db.collection_name.find().count() and db.collection_name.count() in MongoDB

Tags: mongodb

I believe they both return the same results, but essentially which is one is better to use under what scenarios?

Here is what the documentation says:

> Returns the count of documents that would match a `find()` query. The `db.collection.count()` method does not perform the `find()` operation but instead counts and returns the number of results that match a query.

Comment: without criteria? That is important cos without criteria it will pick from meta data but with it will actually cont the rows, but to answer more specifically, none, one is just a symlink for the other

Comment: @divinedragon you might want to reconsider which answer you accept - the one you currently selected definitely contains some inaccuracies.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's no difference. One is implemented in terms of the other:

```
> db.users.count
function ( x ){
    return this.find( x ).count();
}
```

Comment: Oh gosh. I should have checked that.

Comment: Interesting.  See the link in my answer.  In their documentation, they state that 'count' does not perform the find operation

Comment: Yeah. I check that too. Seems rather confusing.

Comment: regardless - neither count() nor find().count() <-which is the exact same thing - perform the find() operation if you include fetching and returning documents that are found.

Answer (score 0):

From my understanding, they are equivalent to each other.  db.collection_name.count() does not use the find() function, therefore, I would assume that it would be slightly better performance wise.

Check out the official MongoDB page referencing this.
[MongoDB Count](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/method/db.collection.count/)

Comment: How does it not perform the `find`? Documentation is outdated, I think.

Comment: I don't think the documentation is outdated: it's just worded oddly. It's using the query to `find`, but not fetching the documents. However, this answer is misleading as it won't perform any better as shown in @SergioTulentsev's answer.